# Making H the subject $Vp=L\left[R^2\cos^{-1}\frac{R-H}{R}-(R-H)\sqrt{2RH-H^2}\right]$

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

I am looking at the paper ["How to Calculate the Volumes of Partially Full Tanks" (via researchgate.net)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301674653_HOW_TO_CALCULATE_THE_VOLUMES_OF_PARTIALLY_FULL_TANKS). On page 2 and equation 5 you are given the formula:

$$Vp=L\left[R^2\cos^{-1}\frac{R-H}{R}-(R-H)\sqrt{2RH-H^2}\right]$$

What I am aiming to do is re-arrange the formula in order to get $H$, height, the subject of the equation. i.e., when a user enters the desired volume, they can find the target height.

I've tried myself and have had a lot of difficulty. If this isn't possible I would like to know if there are any numerical solutions that you could advise.

I greatly appreciate any help with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you cannot get a formula, where $H$ would be explicitly given. In order to get $H$ you should use Newton's method on function:
\begin{align}
f(H)&=L\left[R^2\text{arccos}\left(\frac{R-H}{R}\right)-(R-H)\sqrt{2RH-H^2}\right]-V_p=0
\end{align}
By using
\begin{align}
H_k&=H_{k-1}-\frac{f(H_{k-1})}{f'(H_{k-1})},~~~   k=1,2,\dots\\
f'(H)&=2L\sqrt{2RH-H^2}\\
\end{align}
for the reasonably chosen starting value $H_0$ you get a sequence converging to $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$H=R(1-x) \qquad \text{and}\qquad  a=\frac {V_p}{L\,R^2}$$ and the equation become
$$a=\cos ^{-1}(x)-x \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
The rhs can be very well approximated by a series expansion built around $x=0$
$$\cos ^{-1}(x)-x \sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{\pi }{2}-2 x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{20}+\frac{x^7}{56}+\frac{5
   x^9}{576}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ and, using a few more terms, series reversion would give
$$x=t+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{13 t^5}{120}+\frac{493 t^7}{5040}+\frac{37369
   t^9}{362880}+\frac{4732249 t^{11}}{39916800}+\frac{901188997 t^{13}}{6227020800}+O\left(t^{15}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-a\right)$.

Let us try
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\ 
0.25 & +0.731721 &  +0.732608 \\
 0.50 & +0.567514 &  +0.567540 \\
 0.75 & +0.423413 &  +0.423414 \\
 1.00 & +0.289494 &  +0.289494 \\
 1.25 & +0.161098 &  +0.161098 \\
 1.50 & +0.035406&   +0.035406 \\
 1.75 & -0.089722 &  -0.089722 \\
 2.00 & -0.216301 &  -0.216301 \\
 2.25 & -0.346677 &  -0.346677 \\
 2.50 & -0.484255 &  -0.484258 \\
 2.75 & -0.635296 &  -0.635421 \\
 3.00 & -0.814697 &  -0.818652
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you want to polish the solution, one or two Newton iterations will be sufficient.